# Cannot resolve symbol 'GeoJsonLayer '

Tags: android, json, geojson

I am currently using the Google Maps API and I am attempting to connect a GEOJSON file with markers as a layer to the map.

The line I have taken from the documentation and I am currently trying to use is:

```
GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(getMap(), R.raw.geoJsonFile,
        getApplicationContext());
```

The error is `Cannot resolve symbol 'GeoJsonLayer'`

I have added compile `org.json:json:20090211` to my dependencies but this hasn't solved the problem.

I am coding for Android OS using Android Studio.

Any help please? Thanks

EDIT:

Class code:

```
package com.example.macbookair........;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.maps.android.geojson.GeoJsonLayer;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Maps extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GeoJsonLayer layer1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


      /*  MapFragment mapFrag = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        try {
            GeoJsonLayer layer1 = new GeoJsonLayer(mapFrag.getMap(), R.raw.mapjson,
                    getApplicationContext());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        layer1.addLayerToMap(); */
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    }
}
```

The commented part of the code works but makes the application crash, without the commented code the map works fine and loads fine on my device.

Comment: Do you have the correct/required imports in your class file?

Comment: Which are the correct and/or required imports there is literally nothing in the documentation and I cannot find anything else regarding GeoJson for Android on Google?

Comment: `import com.google.maps.android.geojson.GeoJsonLayer;` They have a demo activity here: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/tree/dba3b0d8a9657ebab8c67a4f50bd731437a229bc/demo

Comment: I didn't have that, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the `google-maps-utils` in your `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:x.y.z'
}
```

Where x.y.z is the version. The latest one is: `0.4`.

You can also need the `google-maps` dependency (and play-services-base), and can be added in build.gradle file as listed:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:x.y.z'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0'
}
```

If you want all the libraries from play-services, you can skip these two dependencies and add all play-services dependencies, like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

Remember that this will add all play-services libs into your APK, and this may cause a 64k method limit and bigger APK size.

[Reference to install play-services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

[Reference to Google Maps Utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

Comment: This fixed it although now from the same line, getMap and geoJsonFile does not work

Comment: What `getMap()` function returns? Is the maps from api? I think this should be `map.getMap()`. But it seems to be another issue.

Comment: it says cannot resolve method getMap() and cannot resolve symbol geoJsonFile, the getMap function should return the map I believe..it was found in the google documentation for maps JSON layer

Comment: did you have the `geoJsonFile` file in `raw` folder?

Comment: the `getMap()` function need to be called from `map` object (you can get by inflating the map fragment into your activity/ fragment

Comment: One of my mistakes was putting raw in the wrong place, I don't understand what you mean by inflating the map fragment?

Comment: add a more generic catch clause, like `catch (Exception e)` to see the stracktrace

Comment: OK this fixed it but the layer does not display on the map?

Comment: @J.Doe I think this is a different question now. You can debug and create a new question after collect the information about the issue. If you think this answer that I post was correct, please mark as accepted.

Comment: To left of the answer there is a vote number and below the check `V` in gray. After click it will turn green.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added dependencies mentioned by Deividi Cavarzan

Plus make sure your mapjson file format is correct

Check for this geojson file code :

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
```

```
    "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": 
            [102.0, 0.5]
     },
     "properties": {
     "prop0": "value0"
     }
    }, {

       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
           "type": "LineString",
           "coordinates": [
             [102.0, 0.0],
             [103.0, 1.0],
             [104.0, 0.0],
             [102.0, 0.0]
             ]
           },
           "properties": {
            "prop0": "value0",
            "prop1": 0.0
           }
    }
]
```

}

To check whether your GeoJson file is correct or not visit : http://geojsonlint.com/